# ClassNotFoundException in Jboss EAP 6 but the jar is in classpath(WEB-INF/lib)

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x, ehcache

In my project I am upgrading the hibernate version 3.2 to 4.1(which is default provided in the JBoss EAP 6.0) and setting my ehcache version to 2.8.0.

I have added the hibernate-ehcache-4.2.8.Final.jar to the classpath(web-inf/lib/) and changed my config for the ehcache like this,

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
```

for loading the Hibernate Classes in classpath I have added dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml like this.

```
 <module name="org.hibernate" export="true"/>
<module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" export="true"/>
```

But when starting server I'm facing this error,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP-9359.jar:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:386) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP-9359.jar:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP-9359.jar:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP-9359.jar:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 69 more
```

I can see that the class is there in the jar. I think it is due to some jboss module classpath issue... asking for suggestions.

P.S. : I'm not using maven. Using at to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the same problem as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811312/why-jboss-can-not-find-mysql-driver-under-hibernate-jpa/20815516#20815516).

In your specific case, the Hibernate JARs are loaded by a classloader that is an ancestor of the classloader that loads `hibernate-ehcache-4.2.8.Final.jar`. Thus these classes cannot see `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.*`.

The solution would be to create a module for EHCache and use that module, instead of including the jar in WEB-INF/lib.